# How to get dynamic id with javascript/jquery from php loop

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have two tables in database which are connected to each other with a foreign key "pid".

I want to show table of projects and when I click a project to show some details from the other table in the database (foreign key).
I am trying to work with Ajax.
The problem is that one part of the table is in one file and the other is in another file (ajax processing). I am trying to put dynamic Id's but I don't know how to get the specific id with javascript/jquery.

Here's the code:

```
     <table class="table table-condensed" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th style="font-style:italic;">NO</th>
            <th style="font-style:italic;">STATUS</th>
            <th style="font-style:italic;">PROJECT NAME ACTIVITIES</th>
            <th style="font-style:italic;">OBJECTIVES/NOTES</th>
            <th style="font-style:italic;">RESPONSIBLE</th>
            <th style="font-style:italic;">START DATE</th>
            <th style="font-style:italic;">COMPLETED DATE</th>
            <th style="font-style:italic;">DURATION</th>
            <th style="font-style:italic;">COMPLETED</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <?php $x = 0; foreach ($projects as $project){
            echo "<tr data-toggle=\"collapse\" data-target=\".demo$x\" class=\"accordion-toggle\">
              <td><button onclick='showTimeline()'>click</button></td>
              <td id=\"pid$x\">$project[pid]</td>
              <td>$project[status]</td>
              <td>$project[project_title]</td>
              <td>$project[notes]</td>
              <td>$project[responsible]</td>
              <td>$project[start_date]</td>
              <td>$project[completed_date]</td>
              <td>$project[duration]</td>
              <td>$project[completed]</td></tr>
              <div id='txtHint$x'></div>";
             $x++;}
            ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>

 function showTimeline(a,i) {
  var pid=document.getElementById("pid"+i).value;
  if (id == "") {
      document.getElementById("textHint"+i).innerHTML = "";
      return;
  } else {
      if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
          // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
          xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      } else {
          // code for IE6, IE5
          xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
      xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
          if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
              document.getElementById("txtHint"+i).innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
          }
      };
      alert(pid);
      xmlhttp.open("GET","ajax_test.php?q="+pid,true);
      xmlhttp.send();
   }
 }
```

Comment: You're on the right way, only that `<td>`s don't have a `value` property and you don't pass the arguments to `showTimeline()` that the function expects.

Comment: sidenote; if you are using jQuery already, I would advice you to use the built-in ajax functions (eg. `$.get()`, `$.post()` or `$.getJSON()`). Saves you a lot of trouble, for example the cross-browser stuff...

Answer (score 0):

firstly, you should break up your code so it reads better:

```
<?php foreach ($data as $key => $value) : ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $value['example']; ?>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

to target a dynamically created element you need to use `$(document)`. The reason being that jQuery works with the DOM on document load, not anything added.

Target like this:

```
$(document).on('event', '#my-dynamic-id', function()
{
    alert('clicked dynamic element')
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Set class to button & td where id available

```html
$(document).on("click", "button", function(){
 var pid = $(this).closest("tr").find(".class name of td where id available").html();
});
```

Comment: @Sohil Sardhara Thanks this works for pid :)
but I need something similar also for txtHint in order to show the result in a specific row of table. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Here is sol.

```html
 <tbody>
          <?php $x = 0; foreach ($projects as $project){
            echo "<tr data-toggle=\"collapse\" data-target=\".demo$x\" class=\"accordion-toggle\">
              <td><button onclick='showTimeline()' data-pid='<?php echo $project[pid]; ?>'>click</button></td>
              <td id=\"pid$x\">$project[pid]</td>
              <td>$project[status]</td>
              <td>$project[project_title]</td>
              <td>$project[notes]</td>
              <td>$project[responsible]</td>
              <td>$project[start_date]</td>
              <td>$project[completed_date]</td>
              <td>$project[duration]</td>
              <td>$project[completed]</td></tr>
              <div id='txtHint$x'></div>";
             $x++;}
            ?>
        </tbody>
```

```js
function showTimeline(a,i) {
  var pid=$(this).data('pid');;
  if (pid == "") {
      document.getElementById("textHint"+i).innerHTML = "";
      return;
  } else {
      if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
          // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
          xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      } else {
          // code for IE6, IE5
          xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
      xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
          if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
              document.getElementById("txtHint"+i).innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
          }
      };
      alert(pid);
      xmlhttp.open("GET","ajax_test.php?q="+pid,true);
      xmlhttp.send();
   }
 }
```